# Denormalize the data

Tags: mysql, normalization, pivot-table

I have three normalized Tables as follows

```
person_info       person_phone                      phone_types
 ------------      -------------------------------     --------------
| id |  Name |    | p_id    |  typeid   | value  |   | id | type    |
|----|-------|    |---------|-----------|--------|   |----|---------|  
|  1 |  Sam  |    |  1      |     1     | 4455544|   |  1 | landline|
|  2 |  Bill |    |  1      |     1     | 889898 |   |  2 | mobile  |
|  3 |  Ted  |    |  1      |     2     | 8898999|   |  3 | fax     |
 ------------      ------------------------------     --------------
```

Every person can have more than one mobile or Landline or Fax. In the above example "SAM" has two landline numbers and 1 mobile number.

I am trying to retrieve the data for SAM as follows

```
SELECT
    pi.id,
    pi.name,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.type = 'landline' THEN pp.value ELSE NULL END) AS landline,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.type = 'mobile' THEN pp.value ELSE NULL END) AS mobile,
    MAX(CASE WHEN pt.type = 'fax' THEN pp.value ELSE NULL END) AS fax,
FROM
    person_phone as pp
    INNER JOIN phone_types AS pt on pp.type_id=pt.id
    INNER JOIN person_info AS pi on pi.id =pp.p_id
GROUP BY pi.id;
```

This gives me just the last added phone number for each time.

```
id       name       landline      mobile         fax
1        Sam        889898        8898999        NULL
```

but I want all the contact numbers which they enter(It can be 'n' number of landline/mobile numbers for each person) displayed as landline1, landline2, landline3 and so on.

If my method is wrong, please suggest some other proper method.

**EDIT**
I am changing the condition from 'n' to a fixed number. No person can have more than 5 Landline, 5 mobile and 2 fax numbers. So there is a Maximum number limit per person now.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that comes to mind is to use [`group concat`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/group-by-functions.html#function_group-concat) to get all the numbers, delimited with something, and then let the application handle the presentation.

Comment: GROUP_CONCAT works but is my DB Structure correct? Can I go ahead with this design.

I changed MAX with GROUP_CONCAT and I am able to get the data as comma delimited. 

Same way I will be grouping person interests and some other tables together like this. Will that affect the process speed?

Comment: I think it's fine. Once you get enormous amounts of data de-normalization can save you some time. Other products, like Cassandra, is built entirely around the concept of de-normalized with no joins.

Comment: My app will have data of approx 25000 persons with their contact numbers. 

Should I worry about migrating to Cassandra?

Comment: Also could you please help me with an example INSERT statement for this structure. 

Every person will enter his Name and contact details. It should automatically insert into both the tables (person_info, person_phone). I am confused how to enter data together into both the tables at once.

Comment: 25000 is very few, no need for Cassandra.